# How to disable stickie note shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, stickies

As titled. The shortcut is conflicting with a shortcut of a chrome extension.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts...

[image: screenshot]

And then Services > Text. Unselect "Make New Sticky Note"

[image: screenshot]